# Two different Objects loading in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am facing a strange problem and am unable to find a solution. I am trying to load a set of objects in Java using Hibernate from MySQl db.

These is a simplified version of my hibernate mappings and code:

```
<class name="org.Foo.Class1" table="class_profile" >
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
            <id name="id" column="id">
                <generator class="native"/>
            </id>
       <property name="amount" column="amount"/>
</class>
<class name="org.Foo.Class2" table="class_profile" >
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
            <id name="id" column="id">
                <generator class="native"/>
            </id>
       <property name="amount" column="amount"/>
</class>
```

This is my code to access, the objects:

```
public List<Class1> loadProfiles(final List<Integer> pIds)
{
  return (List<Class1>)getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback() {
     public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
    return session.createQuery("from Class1 il where il.id in (:idList)")
        .setParameterList("idList", pIds)
        .list();
    }
  });
}
```

Now, when I run my code

```
List<Class1> profiles = fooService.loadProfiles(Arrays.asList(3,4));
```

I get **FOUR objects** *(instead of 2)* in the list profiles - TWO Class1 objects and ***TWO Class2 objects***. Where are the TWO Class2 objects coming from?

Comment: They both map to the same table?  Is Class2 a subclass of Class1?  When you have entity inheritance, the ID fields need to be unique across all subclasses.

Comment: Yes, they both map to the same table. Yes, Class2 derives from Class1 (in Java). With unique Id fields, do you mean that I should have different names in java for the ID fields? [Edit] I'll try it myself :)

Comment: It should only be defined once in java, on Class1.  The column in the database needs to be unique.  There can't be a row that's a Class1 and a row that's a Class2 that have the same ID, or the query behaviour you're seeing would be 'correct.'

Comment: OR you actually don't have a discriminator column set up, and didn't just clip the definition out of the question for brevity?

Comment: Okay, I guess I have designed it incorrectly. I don't have a discriminator. My Table has columns (Id, P1, P2). My Class1 is {Id, P1} and my Class2 inherits Class1 and has additional property {P2}. Inheritance is not in Hibernate but just in Java. I was just trying to reuse Class1 in Java when it already had attributes for Class2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have inheritance between two entities, Hibernate needs to be able to tell which class a particular database row is supposed to represent.  You do this by adding a discriminator class to the table that tells it which class to build to represent the row.

Class2 needs to be declared using a `<subclass/>` element nested inside Class1 that specifies what value of what column is used to tell them apart.

Detials here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperclass

Comment: Makes sense. I Don't think inheritance is something that I need in this case. Separate classes.